# Auto increment ids in cassandra database

Tags: codeigniter, cassandra

How to create unique id in cassandra column families( like auto-increment id in mysql database ) ?

Comment: Each one of these questions should be a separate question. This is too much for one page on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks to reply amo. Let discuss one by one.How to create unique id in cassandra column families( like auto-increment id in mysql database ) ?

Comment: Vijayakumar, I can't answer your question as I'm not familiar with Codeigniter. But you are far more likely to get the answers you need if you take a moment to do at least a cursory Google search and read this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to formulate the kind of well-researched question that gets enough attention to be answered on Stack Overflow. At a minimum I would split these 6 bullet points into 6 separate questions.

Comment: Amo is right about asking the different questions.  Whenever you're ready to create them, I do know the answers to all of these (except #3, which I don't think is possible).  Additionally, you could try searching on this site for each of those questions.  I'm pretty sure that most of them will have answers here already (I answer context-specific versions of #5 here almost on a daily basis).

Answer (score 2):

For unique IDs in Cassandra, you'll want to use UUIDs, which are probabilistically (nearly) guaranteed to be unique.  There are a few [built-in functions in CQL to help with UUIDs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#uuidFun).

Comment: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#uuidFun The link is now dead

Answer (score 1):

You asked for simple query to create table with `uuid`, so there you are:

**create:**

```
CREATE TABLE event (uuid uuid, name varchar);
```

**insert:**

```
INSERT INTO event(uuid, name) values(uuid(), 'john');
```

**select:**

```
SELECT * FROM event LIMIT 1;
```

to select on `name` column you must add new index:

```
CREATE index idx_event_name ON event(name);
```

and now you can select with where:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE name = 'john';
```

[image: select]

Answer (score 0):

If you really *need* integer autoincrement IDs I've written a simple python module that does that after going through stackoverflow and not seeing anything decent that does that specific function. If you don't care about the ID being an integer you're better off using something like UUID which is probably safer and more elegant.

link: https://github.com/qdatum/globalcounter